# How to patch php 8 array_column() index_key parameter no longer casting objects to string

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, php-8

I have recently upgraded a project from php 7 to php 8. I noticed that I was getting an error.

The root cause of the error was this line (which appears in multiple places in the application):

```php
// transform so that the id is the key
$indexed = array_column($results, null, '_id');
```

As the project uses MongoDB in the back-end, this quick one-liner is a massive help as it allows the results of a query to quickly become re-indexed based on the `_id` field.

For example, suppose I had the example array:

```php
$results = [
    [
        '_id' => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId("id1"),
        'a' => 1,
        'b' => 2
    ],
    [
        '_id' => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId("id2"),
        'a' => 3,
        'b' => 4
    ]
]
```

then:

```php
$indexed = array_column($results, null, '_id');
```

would result in:

```php
[
    '_id' => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId("id1") => [
        'a' => 1,
        'b' => 2
    ],
    '_id' => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId("id2") => [
        'a' => 3,
        'b' => 4
    ]
]
```

As you can see, the `_id` field is actually an object of type `MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId`. As such, behind the scenes it was being cast to a string.

It turns out that php 8 has put a stop to that.

I'm currently thinking I'll call an `array_map` or `array_walk` on the results prior to calling `array_column` but as the result set can be potentially very large.

I was wondering if there was a more succinct way to achieve this behaviour?

Comment: Have you looked at [array-multisort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)

Comment: Have you tried `array_combine` (in combination with `array_column`, to extract _only_ the `_id` objects, to then use those as keys)? The manual for that one says, _“Illegal values for key will be converted to string.”_, and doesn’t mention any heightened restrictions under PHP 8. So if the `ObjectId` class has a toString method that can be called implicitly in this situation, that might work.